# CodeIgniter - Variables displayed with "1" before value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know, how to explain my "problem" in title, but I tried my best :). Like can you see in code I'm using CodeIgniter.

Here you have example code. Every attempt to print variable giving me "1" before variable's value. Don't be afraid to say that I'm weak in CI, but I'm just start learning this framework and I don't know everything.

Example Code:
Model: Test_model.php:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_string()
    {
        return 'Example string';
    }
}
```

Controller: Test.php

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function example_method()
    {
        $this->load->model('test_model');
        $data['string'] = $this->test_model->get_string();
        $this->load->view('example_view', $data);
    }
}
```

View: example_view.php:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?=$string;?>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I call test/example_method it shows:
1 Example string

Comment: Possibly somewhere earlier in the code you have code like `echo $somevariable;` where the value of `$somevariable` is a boolean `true` which PHP outputs as `1`.  Perhaps there is an earlier debugging statement left?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I created new project with same result.

Comment: Try `die($this->test_model->test_model());` and check what it outputs before loading view.

Comment: Nothing changed, same result.

Comment: Start by checking what the actual HTML source code received by the browser looks like (actual source code, not DOM), to verify whether that 1 is actually appearing in the place you are assuming it was to begin with.

Comment: One thing you should know is that when you have a method that has the same name as the class, it's considered a constructor. I'm not sure if that's true in your case due to a case difference, but it's generally something you should avoid. Other than that your code seems fine.

Comment: First thing i've thought when i see the question was...too much tests...Change variable names, at least in controller... :)

Comment: @CBroe in the source code returned by the browser there is no "1".
BrianGottier and sinisake code in question is only example, I would never use it under normal conditions :)

Comment: _in the source code returned by the browser there is no "1"_ - and what does that tell you about how likely it is that the part of server-side code you are looking at is responsible for this to begin with? If you replace just `<?=$test;?>` (and nothing else) in your template by a static text `Foobar`, what do you get then?

Comment: Are you showing ALL the code? I built a test using the above code and it works as it should.  No '1' before 'Example string'. I'm forced to believe that somewhere in your code there is a stray '1' character.

Comment: @Micosh If the code you have shown is not the actual code then you definitely have somewhere in your "not shown" code where its writing a 1. So good luck finding it. Did YOU Run your example code and have it showing a 1?????

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a print_r() kicking about in your code displaying something that is Boolean True? Or a var_dump() but with my setup that comes out as 'true'.

Comment: *nothing* in your above code would output that. *somewhere* in your mvc you have a echo/print_r kicking around so you just need to find it. CI doesn't automagically prepend 1's to variables or anything for that matter.

Comment: Please show your `.htaccess` , complete code of your model `Test_model`

Comment: Sorry for my question, I've downloaded fresh copy of CI and now it's okay. My mistake, maybe I changed something in CI_Controller class, or CI_Model class, when I checked how it works. Thanks for all of your time and help!